# Free structures and string member

Tags: c, structure, free

Say I allocated dynamic memory for a structure. Inside that structure is a  `char *` that also has dynamic memory. If I `free(structure)` , will the other field release it's memory as well?

Answer (score 2):

No. The `free()` function simply releases blocks that you acquired via `malloc()` and as far as its concerned it's just a pile of bytes.  It has no knowledge that would allow it to do something like this. You must free the member first:

```
free(ptr->str);
free(ptr);
```

You might find it handy to create a destroy function for your particular type that cleans up all the memory it allocated.  That way you have the logic in one place and your function does know about the details of the struct:

```
void destroy_foo(struct foo *pfoo) {
    free(foo->str);
    free(foo);
}
```

Then you can just call `destroy_foo(foo);`

Comment: thx...been doing it wrong lol. Btw do you know any good method to check for memory leaks?

Comment: @JosipDorvak: Your best bet is a memory debugger, like valgrind.